# Did the Jurassic World park make any other hybrids?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

I just finished watching *Jurassic World* and I am wondering about something. Since we see at least three other hybrid dinosaurs (Stegoceratops; unidentified Pachycephalosaur hybrid; unidentified Therizinosaur hybrid) on a computer screen in the lab near the end, did Jurassic World make any other hybrids, or were these just plans or ideas before they came up with the Indominus Rex?

Also, since it was not created by/for Jurassic World, the Indoraptor is not going to be counted. In-universe answers only please.

Comment: "Find out in the next thrilling instalment of..."

Comment: the question is 'are there other hybrids in Jurassic World?' The Indoraptor was not made by/for Jurassic World. So the answer is invalid either way. I was simply editing the question because I forgot that part when I asked it.

Comment: It seems the answerer edited the title which moved it away from did the park make any others to are there any others in the "World Franchise". I've change the title back, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry for the title edit, it was not very clear that it was referring to the park and not to the franchise. Even now stating that "it was not created for Jurassic World" is a little ambiguous, because being it not a dinosaur that existed in reality, it was in fact "created for Jurassic World (franchise)" even if not for the park.

Comment: I meant the park, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### None that we know of

Except for the *Indominus Rex*, the antagonist of the *Jurassic World* movie and also one of the main exhibits of the eponymous zoo/park:

[image]

which is the only dinosaur hybrid to appear "on the flesh" and created to be an attraction on the park, the only other hybrid [as reported by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cloned_animals_in_the_Jurassic_Park_series#Hybrids) is the so-called *Stegoceratops*:

[image]

It is not known, however, if it was actually created and not shown on-screen, or if the animal depicted in the monitor is just a plan or study.

---

The only other known dinosaur hybrid, also engineered by *InGen* even if not created with the purpose to be exhibited in the Jurassic World park, appears in the movie *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*: it is the *[Indoraptor](http://www.jurassicworld.com/intel/dinosaur/indoraptor)*, made from the DNA's of *Indominus Rex* itself hybridized with that of a *Velociraptor*: 
[image]

Comment: I was actually going to update the question a little bit, but the Indoraptor is a good  place to start

Comment: It seems this answer isn't what the OP was after, you misinterpreted the question slightly.

Comment: I interpreted *Jurassic World* as a franchise, it was not so clear to me that it was intended as the name of the park here.